# How can i get an array of JSON object from a webpage and add each element to the row in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a webpage which contains an array of JSON objects like this :

```
[ 
  {
 id: 10  
name : abc
  },
  {
 id: 11  
name : xyz
  }
]
```

I want these elements to be added to an HTML table so that the table looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I have only made the html table with the headers. I have no idea how to populate the rows.

Comment: You can't ... because JSON is a string, and there's no such thing as a JSON object

Comment: @JaromandaX - that wasn't very nice.

Comment: what do you mean by JSON in a URL? can you give an example of the URL ?

Comment: @VigneshSriram - investigate the Array methods on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: @RandyCasburn - how is that not nice? It's an accurate statement. Better to learn what you are dealing with then forever calling javscript objects "JSON objects", don't you think?

Comment: @JaromandaX - absolutely correct statement, but not helpful. It peeve's me to the Angular Docs use the term "JSON Object". Shouldn't we guide them to the right terminology - after we make the feel like an idiot for asking the question the best they know how?

Comment: @Noface the URL points to a webpage which contains the JSON. I need to get the JSON from there.

Comment: So you’re using an API endpoint that gives you a JSON response, and you want to use that data to populate a table? Can you provide us the endpoint url that we can test? Can you create an MCVE of what you’ve tried so far? There are already a lot of questions on here that deals with populating tables with data from an AJAX request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
//<[!CDATA[
/* external.js */
var doc, bod, M, I, Q, S, tableize, old = onload; // for use on other pages
onload = function(){
if(old)old(); // change old var name if using technique on other pages
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
M = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
Q = function(selector, withinElement){
  var w = withinElement || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
S = function(selector, withinElement){
  var w = withinElement || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
tableize = function(tableArray){
  for(var i=0,tbd=I('tbd'),l=tableArray.length; i<l; i++){
    var o = tableArray[i], tr = M('tr'), id = M('td'), nm = M('td');
    id.innerHTML = o.id; nm.innerHTML = o.name;
    tr.appendChild(id); tr.appendChild(nm); tbd.appendChild(tr);
  }
}
var tableArray = [ 
  {id:10, name:'abc'},
  {id:11, name:'xyz'}
];
tableize(tableArray);
}
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
body{
  background:#000; overflow-y:scroll;
}
.main{
  width:940px; background:#ccc; padding:20px; margin:0 auto;
}
table{
  border-collapse:collapse; font:20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:center;
}
thead{
  background:yellow;
}
th,td{
  padding:0 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <table id='table'>
      <thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr></thead>
      <tbody id='tbd'></tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Only one issue instead of defining the array in the .js file you can get it using the getJSON function.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is simple parsing of the JSON object. Check the link from w3schools which is pretty basic.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Since you tagged this question as Javascript I will assume this will be done using it.

Using the examples from w3 and what you provided:

```
[{ 'id': '10', 'name' : 'abc' } ,{ 'id': '11', 'name' : 'xyz' }]
```

The whole code would run as simple as this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>Create Table from JSON String</h2>
    <table id="demo"></table>
    <script>
      var string = '[{"id": 10, "name": "abc"}, {"id": 11,"name": "xyz"}]';
      var rows = '';
      var jsonData = JSON.parse(string);

      for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        var obj = jsonData[i];
        rows += "<tr><td>" + obj.id +"</td><td>" + obj.name +"</td></tr>"
      }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th></tr>" + rows;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I see there are some answers already, but I just wanted to make you see how easy this could be.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, in order to parse those JSON objects, you will need to either; correct the formatting at the source, or normalize the JSON data on your end prior to processing the data for your table.

When you say you are getting it from a URL, is the data Url-Encoded?

```
?data=%7B%22name%3A%22ABC%22,%22id%22%3A%221%22%7D
```

Or are you getting this data as a response from a request?

You are going to want to make sure you are working with valid JSON.

```
[{"id": 10, "name" : "abc" }, { "id": 11,  "name" : "xyz"}]
```

Once you are working with valid data, I'm certain one or all of the below examples should work for you.

Remember, if you are working with a string of JSON data, parse it first:

```
JSON.parse(data);
```

If you need the data as a string

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

1. **Empty** table
2. **Make** GET request
3. **Foreach** loop the results
4. **Populate** Table Header, Body and Foot

```js
// CLICK EVENT
$( "#btn_ajax_get_all" ).on('click', function() {
// Call function
ajaxGetAll();
console.log('Works up to here.');

});


function ajaxGetAll() {

$.get( "php_pdo_mysql_select_all.php", function( data ) {

console.log('ajaxGetAll() function called.'); 
console.log('[' + data.length + '] records found.');

// A. Empty table
$('#table1').empty();

// B. Add thead tag to table
$('#table1').append('<thead>');
// C. Add tr tag to thead
$('#table1 > thead').append('<tr>');

// D. Add th tags to tr inside thead
$('#table1 > thead > tr:first').append(
$('<th data-type=\"string\">').text('id'),
$('<th data-type=\"string\">').text('name')
);

$('#table1').append('<tbody>');

// E. Run our JSON data returned, through a JQuery for each loop....
$.each(data, function(row_idx, row) {

// Now we can access properties using dot notation.
// *Properties names are case sensitive! Make sure 
// your database field names match the case after the . exactly.

// Create an html <tr> element for each JSON array item...
var $tr = $('<tr>').append(

// ..and fill it with specific row.column_name of our choice.
$('<td>').text(row.id),
$('<td>').text(row.name)
);

// Append each generated html <tr> element to table1
$tr.appendTo($('#table1 > tbody'));

}); // END for each loop

// F. Add tfoot tag to table
$('#table1').append('<tfoot>');

// G. Add tr tag to tfoot
$('#table1 > tfoot').append('<tr>');

// H. Add th tags to tr inside tfoot
$('#table1 > tfoot > tr:first').append(
$('<th>').text('something_else_1'),
$('<th>').text('something_else_2')
);

console.log('4.5 Table table1* populated with [' + data.length + '] records found.');

}, 'json' );

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table1" border="1">

<thead>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>name</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
<tr>
<th>-</th>
<th>-</th>
<tr>
</tfoot>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td>10</td>
<td>abc</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>11</td>
<td>xyz</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>

<p>

<button type="button" id="btn_ajax_get_all">Populate Table</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution using jQuery**

One thing worth to mention about the JSON string is that the members need to be separated by a comma. Also strings need to be between `"` or `'` as specified in https://www.json.org/

json.html

```
[ 
  {
   "id": 10,  
   "name" : "abc"
  },
  {
   "id": 11,
   "name" : "xyz"
  }
]
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table id='data'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>

 <!-- jQuery CDN -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can make an AJAX request using the [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method and set it to convert the response to a [Javascript object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals). Then you can create and add one row to the table for each member in the JSON using the [$.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method.

script.js - *See about the ajax method's **settings** in [jQuery documentation](http:////%20See%20[http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings][4]).*

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "json.html",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
       var $tbody = $("table#data tbody");   // DOM cache

       $.each(data, function(i, obj) {  // parsing the array

          var $tr = $("<tr></tr>");     // Creates a row
          $tr.appendTo($tbody);         // Appends to the table

          var $td = $("<td></td>");  // Creates a cell
          $td.html(obj.id)           // Insert the data
             .appendTo($tr);         // Appends to the row
          $td = $("<td></td>");      // Creates another cell
          $td.html(obj.name)         // Insert the data
             .appendTo($tr);         // Appends to the row
       });
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log("AJAX ERROR",textStatus,errorThrown,jqXHR);
    }
  });
});
```

I tried to keep it simple for better understanding but since the JSON is structured as an array of objects, you can have a nested `$.each()` inside the first `$.each()` so you can read the values of each member of each object independently.

Any questions you can ask.

Answer (score -1):

Use this service (http://json2table.com) to get the html table from your json. And be careful to have valid json string.